# Recycler view item animate when scrolling

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I found and research many way and to custom recycler view item animate when scrolling (space between every item will stretch when scrolling) like [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STIVP.gif), even I referred to many related library such as [recyclerview-animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) or [RecyclerViewItemAnimators](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/RecyclerViewItemAnimators) or creating Animation for each holder onBindViewHolder(). However, all ways above just create animation in the first time load view, can not implement like what animation I want to create. So anyone has done something like that, please help me to resolve that problem. Thank you so much.

EDIT:

I tried to implement OnScrollListener method as @Android recommended. But it do not work properly. This code below show how I implemented them:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                int lastPosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                int firstPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                for (int i = firstPosition; i <= lastPosition; i++) {
                    if (dy < 0) {
                        AnimationUtils.animate(recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i), false);
                    } else {
                        AnimationUtils.animate(recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i), true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

`public class AnimationUtils {
    public static void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, boolean isGoDown){
        ObjectAnimator translateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.itemView, "translationY", isGoDown == true ? 300 : -300, 0);
        translateY.setDuration(300);
        translateY.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2f));
        translateY.start();
    }
}`

Comment: You probably need to create a class that extends from RecyclerView.OnScrollListener that adjusts the height of the views based on scroll speed (dy or dx in onScrolled). Then depending on if you're scrolling up or down, set the view gravity to top/bottom.

Comment: @Android I spent over 2 days to custom RecyclerView.OnScrollListener callback following the way you recommended for me. But it work does not properly, now I do not have any idea to resolve this problem. Could you describe it in detail or suppose another way? Thank you very much

Comment: @HayTrần did you get your solution? I also wanted to do the same effect on scrolling.  If you have any idea or solution. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate RecyclerView item like this.
All you need is, to write an animate method and call that method in `onBindViewHolder()` method.

Here is a example for Fading the RecyclerView item

**Method**

```
public void setFadeAnimation(View view) {
    AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

**Call this method**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    setFadeAnimation(holder.itemView);
    ........

}
```

Comment: That way just apply in the first time itemView holder be created. I want to has animation every when I scroll the recycler view

Comment: Yes it will give you the same effect because the view is created when it comes in the foreground while scrolling.

Comment: I have used it this solution in my app, was working fine . Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yeap, I also used your way recommended, but that animation is not what I want to make. May you watch the gif one again to see the different. Thank you

Comment: ok. I will look into the desired animation. If i come up with some solution, i will let u know

Comment: Thanks in advance. I think if you find out the solution for this problem, you will can make your application become better.

Comment: @RohitSingh Did you find the animation which were you looking for because I am trying something the same animation.

Comment: I did not :( @Spritzig

Comment: @RohitSingh I found how to animate recyclerview items but not the same you are looking for, if you want I will post here the code.
They slide from left to right.

Comment: Yes please. That would be awesome

Answer (score 3):

This is the animation example.

You define the lastPosition

```
private int lastPosition = -1;

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {

    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    } else if ( position < lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

And then only you call the method `onBindViewHolder`

```
setAnimation(viewHolder.itemView, position);
```